# What is the keyboard shortcut for 'Mark as read' in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

In the new Yahoo! mail I can select multiple checkboxes against my email subjects and press <kbd>k</kbd> to perform the action **Mark as read**.

Is there a similar alternative in Gmail?

Comment: And don't forget to enable keyboard shortcuts in settings in the first place.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Gmail "Mark as Read":** <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

---

### Other useful keyboard shortcuts:

- **Display a list of Gmail keyboard shortcuts:** <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> or (<kbd>?</kbd>)
- **Select all unread conversations:** <kbd>*</kbd>, then <kbd>u</kbd>

Also, you could map <kbd>K</kbd> to "Mark as read," just like in Yahoo mail. The "[Custom keyboard shortcuts](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/custom_keyboard.htm)" Gmail labs feature lets you customize your keyboard shortcut mappings. It adds a new Settings tab from which you can remap keys to various actions.

...or you can add a "Mark as Read" button via another Gmail labs feature.

Comment: thnx. I would also like to add one more thing to this answer: If this doesn't work, go to the Settings page and select 'Keyboard shortcuts on'.

Answer (score 18):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> Mark as read - Marks your message as 'read' and skip to the next message.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> Mark as unread - Marks your message as 'unread' so you can go back to it later.

[Full list of Keyboard shortcuts](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594)

Comment: thnx. I would also like to add one more thing to this answer: If this doesn't work, go to the Settings page and select 'Keyboard shortcuts on'.

Answer (score 5):

In Gmail you can use <kbd>?</kbd>, that is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for the <kbd>?</kbd>, you can see the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: And don't forget to enable keyboard shortcuts in settings in the first place.

Comment: Wow. That's very useful. To think I've been using gmail for years...

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> - Mark as Read and move on to the next message.

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594

Answer (score 0):

FYI - you may have to activate Keyboard Shortcuts before they work. They seem to be inactive by default. You can find this option at the bottom of the [?] screen.